# How do you check if a digit is in a int

Tags: python

So I want to find how you find if a digit is in a python int like this:

```
a = 1111  
if 1 in a:
  print("Yes")

else:
  print("No")
```

So as you can see above the code does not work. Im new to stack overflow and python, so sorry if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert both to strings using `str()`, and then do the `in` check:

```
a = 1111
if str(1) in str(a):
  print("Yes")
else:
  print("No")
```